# ussupported url NSURLConnection

Tags: iphone

I want lazyload in my app so I am downloading images using NSURLConnection as you can see

```
premiumRequest=[NSURLRequest requestWithURL:[NSURL URLWithString:@"www.aaaaaaaaa.com/aaaaaaaaa/api/uploads/company_logo/cc2ab63fd3eb564be64b4f21bd083bc7.png"]
                   cachePolicy:NSURLRequestUseProtocolCachePolicy
                timeoutInterval:60.0];

premiumConnection=[[NSURLConnection alloc] initWithRequest:premiumRequest delegate:self];
```

but unfortunately i get following error

```
error downloading: unsupported URL
```

If paste the url on browser it works well but it is not working in NSURLConnection , please help what is the problem with above URL

Answer (score 3):

Try to include appropriate url scheme to your url, e.g.

```
...[NSURL URLWithString:@"http://www...
```

Answer (score 1):

```
NSURL *url = [NSURL URLWithString:@"http://www.invoicera.com/app/api/check_json_api.php?token=CFBF57B78FB183157BF93F0EB00C9C33"];

NSString *jsonRequest = [NSString stringWithFormat:@"&json_data=%@",[[NSString stringWithFormat:@"yourString"] stringByAddingPercentEscapesUsingEncoding:NSUTF8StringEncoding]];

NSLog(@"%@",jsonRequest);

NSData *json_data = [NSData dataWithBytes:[jsonRequest UTF8String] length:[jsonRequest length]];

NSLog(@"The converted String is %@",json_data);

NSMutableURLRequest *request = [[NSMutableURLRequest alloc] initWithURL:url];


[request setHTTPMethod:@"POST"];
[request setHTTPBody: json_data];
NSLog(@"%@",json_data);
// [request setValue:@"application/json" forHTTPHeaderField:@"Accept"];
[request setValue:@"application/x-www-form-urlencoded" forHTTPHeaderField:@"Content-Type"];
//[request setValue:@"application/json" forHTTPHeaderField:@"Content-Type"];
[request setValue:[NSString stringWithFormat:@"%d", [json_data length]] forHTTPHeaderField:@"Content-Length"];
[request setHTTPBody:[[jsonRequest stringByAddingPercentEscapesUsingEncoding:NSASCIIStringEncoding]
                      dataUsingEncoding:NSUTF8StringEncoding 
                      allowLossyConversion:YES]];
```

//  [NSURLConnection connectionWithRequest:[request autorelease] delegate:self];

```
NSURLConnection *nsUrlConnection=[[NSURLConnection alloc]
                                  initWithRequest:request 
                                  delegate:self];

// Successful connection.
if (nsUrlConnection) {

    [self indicatorView];
   // [self initSpinner];
   // [self spinBegin];

    NSMutableData *data = [[NSMutableData alloc] init];
    self.receivedData=data;
    [data release];
} 
// Unsuccessful connection.
else {

}  
// Clean up
[url release];
[request release];
```

Set properties properly after that you will net get any error.

give Vote to the answer by pressing up arrow of answer.

Answer (score 0):

```
    NSURL *webURL = [NSURL URLWithString:@"YOur URL here"];
    NSMutableURLRequest *request = [[NSMutableURLRequest alloc] initWithURL:webURL];
    [request setTimeoutInterval:60.0];
    [request setHTTPMethod:aStrGetOrPost];
    NSError *error;
    NSURLResponse *response;

    NSData *returnData = [NSURLConnection sendSynchronousRequest:request returningResponse:&response        error:&error];

    if(returnData) 
        {
            //Do what you wish to do with the data
        }
        else 
        {
            //Display failure alert
        }
```